# I have a MySQL Date formatting that returns old records

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm a little befuddled. My client selects 10-01-2016 ($datefrom variable) and 10-02-2016 ($dateto variable). When executed, it will return the dates for 2015 and 2016.

Here is my php code:

```
$datefrom = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['datefrom']);

$dateto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['dateto']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Dates WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto') AND date_type='1'";
```

When I run the following query in MySQL (just replacing the variables):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Dates WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '10-01-2016' AND '10-02-2016') AND date_type='1';
```

It runs and gives both 2015 and 2016 date records.

When I change the DATE_FORMAT lines and the variables to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Dates WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-02') AND date_type='1';
```

It runs fine, only giving 2016 date records.

the system is about a year old, LOL, hence why it is now giving the errors. How do I correct the SQL syntax to have it query correctly without having to change the php code down the line that uses the %d-%m-%Y formatting?

Thanks for any help you guys can provide,
Jim

Comment: So that's the 2016th day of the 1st month of the 10th year?

Comment: I woutd parse the dates in PHP to avoid using the DATE_FORMAT in the sql sentence. Your query will parse all the dates of all the table. If you instead pass the date correctly formatted this will not be done and maybe the error is in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates aren't in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, MySQL will be comparing them as **STRINGS**, not dates.

That means

```
10-23-2016 > 10-24-2015
```

is **FALSE**, because `3` is SMALLER than `4` in string comparisons. The fact that we humans know it's a date and know that 2016 comes after 2015 is irrelevant. MySQL isn't human, it isn't an AI, and when it sees strings, it compares them as strings.

If you want to do 'date math' in MySQL, then you **MUST** use the native formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$datefrom = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['datefrom']);

$dateto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['dateto']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Dates WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$datefrom','%m-%d-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$dateto','%m-%d-%Y')) AND date_type='1'";
```

STR_TO_DATE will convert formatted string to date,

DATE_FORMAT() will convert formatted string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Dates WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$datefrom', '%m-%d-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$dateto', '%m-%d-%Y')) AND date_type='1'";
```